# prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=3 runtime=napi arch=arm libc= platform=linux)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi4, npm-package, lasercutting

I am a new-b at this hole R-pi thing and linux
it seems like the problem is that I have a 64bit processor and the code is build for 32.
is there a way to fix this?

```
lw.comm-server $ npm install node-hid

> node-hid@2.1.2 install /home/----/lw.comm-server/node_modules/node-hid
> prebuild-install --runtime napi || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=3 runtime=napi arch=arm libc= platform=linux)
Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libusb-1.0' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags-only-I | sed s/-I//g' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.61-v7l+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/----/lw.comm-server/node_modules/node-hid
gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-hid@2.1.2 install: `prebuild-install --runtime napi || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-hid@2.1.2 install script.
```

I am trying to install laserweb on the pi.
thanks for your help
Danny